# How to access object using jQuery and HTML select element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this structure:

```
var data = {
    'horizontal':{
         'static':[1,3,5,7,9],
         'dynamic':[2,4,6,8]
    },
    'vertical':{
         'static':[1,3,5,7,9],
         'dynamic':[2,4,6,8]
    }
};
```

I have this HTML objects:

```
Direction:
<select id="direction">
    <option value="horizontal">Horizontal</option>
    <option value="vertictal">Vertictal</option>
</select>

Type:
<select id="mytype">
    <option value="static">Static</option>
    <option value="dynamic">Dynamic</option>
</select>
```

Can I access to the `data.horizontal.static[2]` somehow like this?

```
var result = data.[ $('#direction').val() ].[ $('#mytype').val() ][2];
```

Is there any way?

Comment: remove dots between ']' and '['

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can I access a specific value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-i-access-a-specific-value)

Comment: FYI, [there is no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). JSON is a textual data exchange format. You simply have a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is close.... you need:

```
var result = data[ $('#direction').val() ][ $('#mytype').val() ][2];
```

Note (no periods between square brackets)

Comment: Ahh, you understood the question more than I did, this is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

try remove dots

```
var result = data[ $('#direction').val() ][ $('#mytype').val() ][2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what value you're wanting here, but this is how you access your values:

```
console.log(data['horizontal']);
console.log(data['horizontal']['static']);
console.log(data['horizontal']['static'][2]);
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jj49G/